Is there any machine learning method for finding quantum error correction codes?
To define a quantum error correction code, first one needs to model noise, such as Pauli noise, dephasing noise, etc.
Then according to the noise, look for the code space, stabilizer, and logical operators.
The whole process is really hard and the performance of defined codes may not be that good.
So I want to know if there is any machine learning method for finding quantum error correction codes. Given the settings of our noise, the algorithm searches for a good QEC code automatically with a high distance and $p_{th}$, and low consumed physical qubits.

Such a things doesn't exist for classical codes...if it did it would put a lot of people out of work. So don't expect much for quantum codes.

We've been collecting references here:
https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/reinforcement_learning

At least in this paper, they use reinforcement learning for optimizing QEC codes. Though, they constrain the search to a family of surface codes.

I can't quite understand if ML is a promising approach for QEC. +1 for an interesting paper.
